# Customized page cannot print in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have setup "HP OfficeJet Pro 3610" network printer with my system using CUPS.

I can't print from firefox with custom size, when i click print button my printer shows "status: Processing" for long time.

But i can able to print using default paper size such as US Legal, A3,  A4, A5, etc..
I'm stuck with this issue now, what can i do to solve this?
what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with Ubuntu, rather than with the printer, as I cannot print anything from Firefox, or any image printing program, from Ubuntu 12.04, on my Ubuntu compatible Samsung ML-2162; and it was the same with my old Lexmark.

Ubuntu simply seems to lack any decent image printing program, and there seems to be no interest in developing one. I have tried all of them, and none of them work. Ubuntu seems to be focused purely on cloud storage and sharing/publishing over the ether.

One solution is to save the page/image as a PDF document, or print to file as a PDF, and then print from that. It's a bit of a long work around, but it usually works.

Comment: For some unknown reason the Linux printer drivers from the official Samsung website sometimes do not install in the usual way, and furthermore the driver archives do not always include the installation instructions in the archive. However if there is an install.sh file in the Samsung ML-2162 driver archive, you could try running that file as root.